# 'Text' property cannot be set from a property trigger and appear in the trigger's condition at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-style

I want to replace the text "0" with "" using trigger.. But getting the below compile error.

'Text' property cannot be set from a property trigger and appear in the trigger's condition at the same time.

```
<TextBox MaxLength="10">
    <TextBox.Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="d1">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: The error message seems very clear to me, and reasonable. WPF doesn't want you setting off an infinite loop, which is what could happen in this situation. Once a trigger no longer applies (because the setter changed the value), WPF will revert to the bound value, assuming there is one, which could set off the trigger again, which would cause the trigger to no longer apply, and so on. There's not enough context in your question to know what the broader goal is, but clearly you're simply thinking about your problem wrong. Fix the question, make sure to include a good [mcve] and explain better.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message clearly tells you, you can't do this. That is set the same property that you trigg on.

Some options include:

- If the `TextBox` is bound to a source property, you could use a converter to convert the string "0" to `string.Empty`: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/868163/IValueConverter-Example-and-Usage-in-WPF
- If the `Text` property is bound to a `string` property, you could simply return `string.Empty` instead of "0" from this one.
- If it is an `int` property, you could change its type to `int?` and return `null` instead of `0`.
- If the `Text` property is not data-bound, you could handle the `TextChanged` event something like this:

  ```
  private bool _handle = true;
  private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (_handle)
      {
          _handle = false;
          TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
          if (textBox.Text == "0")
              textBox.Text = string.Empty;
          _handle = true;
      }
  }
  ```

So you have many options but using a trigger isn't one of them.